# ros getparam() question

Tags: ros, getparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

In reading the tutorial "http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server", I'm confused in understanding "nh.getParam("/global_name", global_name)". Should I interpret it as "get "/global_name" from the parameter server, and put it in "global_name""? And the "/" means what?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157841/ros-getparam()-question/) by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2014-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. "/global_name" is the name of the variable on the parameter server. global_name is the variable in your code. The "/" is part of the variable name.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1